# Using JavaScript's Document.write() to create a HTML link

Tags: javascript, html

I have an URL stored in a variable (var URL).

I thought this would work:

```
document.write("<a href='"+url+"'>LINK</a>");
```

But it isn't! Any solution??

This is exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
         <script>

          var url2="https://wa.me/(phonenumber)/?text=";
          var url3="<data:post.title/>";
          var url4=url2+url3;
          var url5="<a href='"+url4+"'>ORDER VIA WHATSAPP</a>";
          document.write(url5);

              </script>
```

(EDIT: IT'S WORKING NOW. SOLVED!)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean? How does it _not work_? Works for me on this very page if I set `var url = 'https://example.com'` and then run your line of code in the console

Comment: it displays nothing in the blogger cms when I use the <a></a> tags inside the String. I guess the compiler misinterprets it.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do:

        
```
<script>
          
          var url2="https://wa.me/(phonenumber)/?text=";
          url2=url2+"<data:post.title/>";
          var url5="<a href='"+url4+"'>ORDER VIA WHATSAPP</a";
console.log(url5);
console.log("hi");
          document.write(url5);

              </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work instead of document.write().

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="Place to insert"></div>
    <script>
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.textContent = 'Link Title';
      link.href = Your URL;
      document.getElementById('Place to insert').appendChild(link);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

variables are case sensitive, this should work.

```js
document.write("<a href='"+URL+"'>LINK</a>");
```

Also if you really want to use vanilla js to dynamically create an html element, I would recommend avoiding document.write because of cross site scripting attacks.

```js
var url = 'www.yoururl/cpm'
var a = document.createElement('a')
a.textContent = 'LINK'
a.href = url 
document.body.appendChild(a)
```

Comment: `URL` is already a JavaScript global and should not be overwritten. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Yes, just stating why his original problem doesn't work.

Comment: Don't forget the `http(s)://` prefix on the URL. For all we know, that could actually be OP's problem 

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the side effect of document.write(). I will try the other method recommend by you. And, in my actual code,  the variables were lower case (url), so it's not an issue. I guess the CMS might interpret differently? It's Blogger. When I use CDATA, it completely ignores my JS code.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you write same name

```js
var url="https://www.google.com.tr/"
document.write("<a href='"+url+"'>LINK</a>");
```

Comment: This isn't due to the variable. In my actual code, the variable was in lowercase. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

use    document.write have 
it is not Good beacuse it delete all the contents inside the calling element 
so use `innerHTML` or `insertAdjacentHTML` instead or create the link like this

```
 let a = document.createElement('a');
 a.href = '#';
```